# while loop with an array in mips

Tags: arrays, while-loop, mips

Consider the following c or java-like code:
`int i = 0; int x = 5; int A[10];` 
 declare an array of integers with 10 element `while (i < 10) { A[i] = i+x; i++; }`
Write a MIPS program to implement the program. Use as few instructions as possible.

I can't seem to figure this out.
Heres what i have done.

```
# i=0, x=5. Array is 10 elements. (While i<10, A[i]=i+x, i++.)
# Array should be [5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14]
    .data
intgrs: .word 0:10  # array of 10 elements to contain integers
size:   .word 10    #size of array
    .text
    .globl main
main:
    la $t0, intgrs  # load address or array
    la $t5, size    # load address of size variable
    lw $t5, 0($t5)  #load array size
    li $t2, 0   # i=0
    li $t6, 5   # x=5
loop:
    add $t4, $t2, $t6 # i+x
    sw $t4, 0($t0)  # A[0] = 0+5 = 5
    add $t2, $t2, 1 # i++
    beq $t2, $t5, loop
exit:   li $v0, 10  # exit system call
    syscall
```

Comment: Ok, so what is the issue?

Comment: right. sorry. it keeps stopping before the value of $t2 is equal to $t5. basically it runs once and then stops.

Answer (score 1):

Change `beq $t2, $t5, loop` to `blt $t2, $t5, loop`.

Comment: Normally you'd want `bne` because that's a single machine instruction, while `blt` is a pseudo-instruction for `slt` / `bnez`.